# Drools 'LIKE' condition - does it exist?

Tags: drools

I am new to drools and tried searching the API doc but couldn't find anything about the comparison keyword 'LIKE'.  I have successfully created rules with <, >, <=, >=, ==, != but now I am trying to create a rule using 'LIKE' keyword.  I was told by the seniors that it should work like SQL like keyword.  Below is my rule from the drl file but I am getting an error about mismatched input 'LIKE' in rule 5495Y

using drools 5.6.0

```
**From DRL File:**
rule "5495Y"
agenda-group "1"
date-effective "04-Sep-2017"
when
JournalEntry : JournalEntry( (ledgerCd=="COMN") && accountNumber LIKE 1234 
&& entryTypeCode == "Y" );
DroolsUtil : DroolsUtil(  );
then
JournalEntry.addConsequence("rejectReason","kk like test");
JournalEntry.addConsequence("sendToLedger","N");
DroolsUtil.reclassEntry(JournalEntry,"NOCHG", "5495Y");
end

**Exact Error I am getting:**
[38583,71]: [ERR 102] Line 38583:71 mismatched input 'LIKE' in rule "5495R"
[38596,71]: [ERR 102] Line 38596:71 mismatched input 'LIKE' in rule "5495Y"
[0,0]: Parser returned a null Package

11:09:17,118 ERROR main ReclassAccountingRuleJob:132 - java.lang.Exception: Know
ledgeBuilder has errors. DRL File parsing error
java.lang.Exception: KnowledgeBuilder has errors. DRL File parsing error
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do? What should "like 1234" mean? - SQL "like" does pattern matching, and the Drools manual will tell you that there is a "matches" operator for pattern matching.

Comment: may be "like 1234*" or "like 1234%" should mean anything that begins with 1234.  I am sure about the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Drools has support for regular expression matching (much more powerful than the `LIKE` operator in SQL) for String type attributes:

```
rule "5495Y"
when
    JournalEntry : JournalEntry(
        ledgerCd == "COMN",
        accountNumber matches ".*1234.*", //accountNumber must be of type String. Otherwise, you will need to convert it first.
        entryTypeCode == "Y" 
    )
    DroolsUtil : DroolsUtil(  )
then
    ...
end
```

For more information about the `matches` operator you can read [this section](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/drools-docs/html_single/#_the_operator_code_matches_code) of the documentation.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot Esteban. Much appreciated.

Comment: It it worked, make sure to mark the question as answered.

Comment: I tried creating a rule with accountNumber matches "1234.*" but it didn't match account numbers starting with 1234.

Comment: What's the type of your `accountNumber` attribute?

Comment: it's a string, I also tried with some other attributes which are alphanumeric and it still didn't work.